# C++ inserting into a map<double, multimap<int, Object*>>

Tags: c++, maps

How does one insert into a `map<double, multimap<int, Object*> >`?
I tried `mymap.insert(make_pair(double, make_pair(int, Object*)));`. Furthermore how do you access the `Object*` when iterating through it?
I tried `it->second->second`.

Comment: As the second in that inserted pair is *not* a `multi_map<int,Object*>` instance (it's a simple pair of `int` and `Object*`), its failure to work isn't surprising. And since `it->second->second` makes no sense in *any* paradigm of a map of keys-to-maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be wanting:

```
using MyMap = std::map<double, std::multimap<int, Object*> >;

MyMap mymap;
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(dbl, std::multimap<int, Object*>());
```

To enumerate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct Object {};

int main()
{
    using MyMap = std::map<double, std::multimap<int, Object*> >;

    MyMap mymap;
    auto ins = mymap.insert(std::make_pair(42.0, std::multimap<int, Object*>()));

    Object obj1, obj2;
    ins.first->second.insert(std::make_pair(7, &obj1));
    ins.first->second.insert(std::make_pair(7, &obj2));

    for (auto const& pr : mymap)
    {
        std::cout << "dblkey: " << pr.first << '\n';
        for (auto const& pr2 : pr.second)
        {
            std::cout << "\tintkey: "<< pr2.first
                      << ", value: " << static_cast<const void*>(pr2.second) << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** (pointer values vary, obviously)

```
dblkey: 42
    intkey: 7, value: 0x7fff5fbff160
    intkey: 7, value: 0x7fff5fbff158
```

In the end, your problem was a type issue more than anything else. You were attempting to insert a `std::pair<int, Object*>` where a `std::multimap<int, Object*>` instance belonged.

Answer (score 2):

In a `std::map<double, std::multimap<int, Object*> >`, the second value is a single `std::multimap` object, but you are trying to set it to a `std::pair` object instead.  `std::multimap` does not have a constructor that accepts a `std::pair` as input, which is why your code fails.

You need to construct a `std::multimap` object to insert into the `std::map`, eg:

```
double d = ...;
int i = ...;
Object *obj = ...;

std::multimap mm;
mm.insert(std::make_pair(i, obj));
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(d, mm));
```

Or:

```
mymap[d].insert(std::make_pair(i, obj));
```

When iterating the `std::map`, it will return an iterator to a `std::pair` where `->first` is `double` and `->second` is `std::multimap<int, Object*>`.

When iterating the `std::multimap`, it will return an iterator to a `std::pair` where `->first` is `int` and `->second` is `Object*`.

```
auto iter1 = mymap.begin;
while (iter1 != mymap.end())
{
    auto &mm = iter1->second; // mm = std::multimap<int, Object*>

    auto iter2 = mm.begin();
    while (iter2 != mm.end())
    {
        auto obj = iter2->second; // obj = Object*
        // use obj as needed...
        ++iter2;
    }
    ++iter1;
}
```

This would be simpler if you used a [ranged-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead:

```
for (auto &v1: mymap) // v1 = std::pair<double, std::multimap<int, Object*> >
{
    auto &mm = v1.second; // mm = std::multimap<int, Object*>

    for (auto &v2: mm) // v2 = std::pair<int, Object*>
    {
        auto obj = v2.second; // obj = Object*
        // use obj as needed...
    }
}
```